# Where is a Zend Log writing to?

Tags: php, logging, zend-framework

In a Zend Framework Application I am working with, the log object is stored in the Registry. It is an instance of `Zend_Log`. How can I find out what file it is writing to, since I am not initializing it?

I've tried `var_dump`'ing the object and its public methods, but they don't seem to be helpful. I've also poked around in the usual places like the apache error log, which is *not* written to when I use `$log->err()`. I'm not looking to set the path to any particular location, I just need to know where it is writing to right now, so I can check that my log messages are being written.

Comment: ZF doesn't setup logging by default, so there should be some configuration somewhere (possibly application.ini) which should include the log location.